# Time limit for progress dialogue in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, progressdialog

How can I set time limit for ProgressDialog in android application.Can anybody help me for this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

pass the Dialog object and time to this method

```
public void timerDelayRemoveDialog(long time, final Dialog d){
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {           
        public void run() {                
            d.dismiss();         
        }
    }, time); 
}
```

Comment: @ dennis    this is my code:-                                                  "public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
     
        ProgressDialog p= new ProgressDialog(this);
       p.setCancelable(true);
       p.setMessage("Loading...");
           p.show();
           
             getFeed(RSSFEEDOFCHOICE);}  "                     how can i use the answer in my code .I want it for 10 seconds.Please help

Comment: @bejoy call this method like   timerDelayRemoveDialog(10000,p);

Answer (score 0):

You can use android timer ,below for the demo i have it wait for 5seconds.
Hope it answers. Do let me know of any more query.

```
Timer timer;// Declare it above    
     timer = new Timer();//Initialized
                    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {


    // cancel the progress dialogue after 5 seconds
                            progress.cancel(); 
                            timer.cancel();
                        }
                    }, 5000 ,5000);
```